# Android textColor won't change colour

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, textview

I have tried...

`android:textColor="#ff0000"`

&

`TextView app_nameTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.app_name);`
`app_nameTextView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));`

but it won't change the text colour, is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Try to clean your project and run.

Comment: where you written the logic? currently which color is showing for your textview RED or WHITE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
 tv.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
```

Answer (score 1):

try `android:textColor="#FFFFFF"` hex code for white is `#FFFFFF`

Answer (score 0):

What about Spannables? For example:

```
Spannable spanText = new SpannableString("INFO: Some spanned result.");
spanText.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.GREEN), 0, spanText.length(), 0); 

area.append(spanText);
```