# Changing text color with time

Tags: java, android

I want my text color to change every second, but I don't actually know how to start doing something, which depends on passing time. Could you give me couple examples, or say what method I should use? Maybe what I could read to know more about it?

Comment: i don't even know what I can try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a start, take a look at the `Timer` and `TimerTask` classes. For example, to run a beep periodically you'd use something like:

```
timer.schedule(new RemindTask(),
        1250,        //initial delay
        1*100);  //subsequent rate
```

}

Changing colors of text - various ways to do that..

[Source](http://enos.itcollege.ee/~jpoial/docs/tutorial/essential/threads/timer.html)

[Android timer class](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html)

[Android textColor won't change colour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12245240/android-textcolor-wont-change-colour)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do the trick, and doesn't require the use of a `Timer` or `TimerTask`:

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        Thread thread = new Thread()
        {

            public void run()
            {
                while (true){
                    Random myColor = new Random();
                    TextView tv = tv.setTextColor(Color.rgb(myColor.nextInt(255), myColor.nextInt(255), myColor.nextInt(255)));
                    try
                    {
                        Thread.sleep(1000); // 1 second
                    } catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        thread.start();
    }
}
```